# How to git pull rebase using GitPython library?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am using GitPython library ([GitPython Documentation](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/))

The following code is working fine for git pull, but how to use **git pull --rebase** ?"

```
import git 

g = git.cmd.Git(git_dir)
g.pull()
```

is there any function or parameter we need to add for **git pull --rebase** ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried g.pull("--rebase")

Answer (score 4):

If you create an origin object like:
origin = Remote(repo, 'origin')

You can do:
origin.pull(rebase=True)

You can do the same with your git.cmd object
g.pull(rebase=True)

Comment: Note that there is an issue with GitPython when doing a pull with rebase [issue](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/718) you may want to call the repo.__del__() function after that in case you get a BadName exception